# Input capture value is double in ATmega128

Tags: c, embedded, atmega, avr-gcc

I am learning embedded C with ATmega128 and Atmel Studio.

I want to write code that shows the temperature and humidity from a sensor.

I am learning Input Capture and my first question is:

I get IC with value 5000 (period) but I think 2500 is correct. Am I calculating it right? If so, do you have any idea why IC has the wrong value?

```
16000.000/64 = 250000

1 second      250000 puls

100 ms          x = 2500
```

Board info:

```
avr128

16.000.000 external clock.

 

philips puls generator info:

Repitation 100 mili s
Duration 10 ms
5 volt
```

My code

```
    volatile uint32_t iccnt=0,ovfcnt=0;
    volatile uint32_t myCapt [2],lastCapt; 

//__________________________

void initTimer()
{
    TCNT1 =0;//Max=65535
    TCCR1B |= 1<<CS10 | 1<<CS11 ;
    // 1<<CS10 | 1<<CS11 ;//16000000/16=250000
    //250000/65535=3.81
    //TCCR1B |= 1<<WGM13  |1<<WGM12;
    TIMSK |= 1<<TOIE1;
    TIFR = 1<<TOV1;
    sei();
} 

void initInputCapture()
{
    // First Capture on rising edge
    TCCR1B |=1<<ICES1;
    //ic intrrupt flag enable
    TIMSK |= 1<< TICIE1;
    // set input pin to get signal

}
void initlcd()
{
    lcd_init(LCD_DISP_ON_CURSOR_BLINK);
    lcd_clrscr();
}
void ShowA(unsigned int a)
{
    char aa[11];
    if (a >32000) {
        itoa(a - 32000,aa,10);
        lcd_puts("32000+");
        lcd_puts(aa);
    } else {
        itoa(a,aa,10);
        lcd_puts(aa);
    }
}
ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect)
{
    ovfcnt++;

}
ISR(TIMER1_CAPT_vect)
{

    iccnt++;

    myCapt[iccnt % 2] = ICR1 - lastCapt;
    lastCapt = ICR1; 

}

void ShowCaptureTime2()
{
    lcd_clrscr(); 

    ShowA (iccnt);
    lcd_puts(": \n");
    ShowA(myCapt[(iccnt - 1) % 2]);

        for (int j=0;j<(1000) ;j++)
        {
            for (int i=0;i<4000;i++)
            {

            }
        }

}

//*******************************
//*******************************
int  main(void)
{
    DDRG = 0b11111111;

    int cnt = 0;

    initlcd();
    initTimer();
    initInputCapture();

    while(1)
    {
        ShowCaptureTime2();     

    }
}
```

Comment: "16MHz external clock" doesn't say much, since apparently the timer clock is inherited from the system bus clock. I don't know this part, but according to RTFM for register XDIV: "The XTAL Divide Control Register is used to divide the Source clock frequency by a number in the range 2 - 129." If I understand this correctly, the fastest bus clock you can get on this MCU is the external clock divided by 2.

Comment: Where do you set up system clock and other such fundamental things? Is this done in some compiler-delivered code which it spews out to execute before main? Try to get rid of such files: it is always best to actually understand your hardware, instead of blindly relying on some icky start-up code made by the compiler vendor.

Comment: @Lundin - if bit 7 is zero the crystal is not divided.

Comment: You very very likely do not want floating point arithmetics on ATmega. Even less `double`. It bloats your code and is **slow**. Use fixed-point/integer arithmetic.

Comment: thanks all, 
I could find the answer yesterday. 
code has no problem. Pulse generator work not correktly! incorrect input!!!!

Comment: Sounds like we should close it as "could not be reproduced" since the problem was with external circuitry.

Answer (score 0):

I could find the answer yesterday. code has no problem. Pulse generator work not correktly! incorrect input!!!! – samsoft